# Jquery dialog IE6 and IE7 hangs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using jquery to show a dialog box, but its causing IE6 and IE7 to hang. Suggestions anybody? Thanks

```
  $(""#" + this.pnlConfirmPanel.ClientID + @""").dialog(
                        {
                           autoOpen: false,
                            modal:true,
                             resizable: false,
                            draggable: false
                        })
```

The line which causes it to hang is:

```
modal:true
```

**Update 1**
Sorry must have clarified its a asp.net page, the resulting code looks like this:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_JobAdmin1_pnlConfirmPanel").dialog(
                        {
                           autoOpen: false,
                            modal:true,
                             resizable: false,
                            draggable: false
                        })
```

If I remove modal:true, the dialog box shows and closes fine in both IE6 and IE7. Its when I add the modal:true line, that causes the browser to crash...

**Update 2**
Thought I'd post the rest of the javascript and html, just in case somebody would like to try it out. (To simplify I shorted the long identifier I had for the panel  above)

```
<script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.5.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $().ready(function () {
        $("#ConfirmPanel").dialog(
                        {
                            autoOpen: false,
                            width: 400,
                            height: 300,
                            modal: true
                        });

        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $("#ConfirmPanel").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });



</script>
```

```
<span id="lblClicked"></span>
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Test" id="Button1" />
<div id="ConfirmPanel" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;">
<input type="submit" name="btnClose" value="" id="btnClose" />
    <h2>
        Hello</h2>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: @rauland: What's with all the quotes in the selector?

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but have you tried adding a semicolon to the end of your call to `dialog`?

Comment: Good job! If only more web pages caused IE 6 and 7 to hang.

Comment: @jacob Good spot, but it wasnt the problem...

Comment: Can you elaborate on saying that IE is hanging?  Does the whole window become unresponsive, or are the dialog buttons unclickable?

Comment: @Jacob the whole browser becomes unresponsive,..

Comment: I made a JS Fiddle of it:  http://jsfiddle.net/sh9qM/  Does it work in other browsers?  Have you tried earlier versions of the jQuery libraries?

Comment: @Steve Thanks! Never heard of JS Fiddle so I'll start to use it from now on. As you said in the end it was the version I downgraded from 1.5.2 to 1.5.1 and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Steve - can you post that as the answer so the asker can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler - Is that the general practice here?  I'll do it, thanks.

Comment: @Steve - If the poster has his question answered in the comments, the post will remain "unanswered" unless you put your solution in as an actual answer. You might as well get the rep for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a JS Fiddle of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/sh9qM/

Does it work in other browsers?

Have you tried earlier versions of the jQuery libraries?

EDIT:  Since you have indicated that moving to an earlier version of jQuery solved the problem, perhaps you could enter it as a bug at the jQuery web site.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well. By simply changing the position attribute from fixed to absolute on the "ui-widget-overlay" class, I resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My colleagues and I encountered this issue today - our solution was to update our jQuery UI CSS file to the latest version.